# Does Spring Test (or Junit?) perform some implicit cleanup?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Do you know why on earth it works? Here's an MRE:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/create_user_table.sql", "/insert_user.sql"}
)
public class H2DemoApplicationTest {
    @Test
    void testNothing() {
    }

    @Test
    void testNothingOneMoreTime() {
    }
}
```

```sql
-- create_user_table.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```sql
-- insert_user.sql

INSERT INTO users
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
```

```
# knocked myself out. gimme all them logs!! i don't care about all your properties, spring

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace

logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.jdbc=DEBUG
```

Notice I don't perform any cleanup. In other words, before the second test, inserting a row with the same identifier should throw an exception!

Here's a snippet from the console log:

```
2023-11-10T13:59:35.438+03:00  INFO 1788 --- [           main] c.example.h2_demo.H2DemoApplicationTest  : Started H2DemoApplicationTest in 6.934 seconds (process running for 10.351)
2023-11-10T13:59:35.581+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] .s.t.c.j.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener : Processing merged @SqlConfig attributes for execution phase [BEFORE_TEST_METHOD] and test class [com.example.h2_demo.H2DemoApplicationTest]
2023-11-10T13:59:35.584+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] .s.t.c.j.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener : Executing SQL scripts: [class path resource [create_user_table.sql], class path resource [insert_user.sql]]
2023-11-10T13:59:35.587+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [create_user_table.sql]
2023-11-10T13:59:35.590+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(50) )
2023-11-10T13:59:35.594+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [create_user_table.sql] in 4 ms.
2023-11-10T13:59:35.597+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [insert_user.sql]
2023-11-10T13:59:35.605+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')
2023-11-10T13:59:35.605+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [insert_user.sql] in 7 ms.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-11-10T13:59:36.900+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] .s.t.c.j.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener : Processing merged @SqlConfig attributes for execution phase [BEFORE_TEST_METHOD] and test class [com.example.h2_demo.H2DemoApplicationTest]
2023-11-10T13:59:36.900+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] .s.t.c.j.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener : Executing SQL scripts: [class path resource [create_user_table.sql], class path resource [insert_user.sql]]
2023-11-10T13:59:36.901+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [create_user_table.sql]
2023-11-10T13:59:36.902+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(50) )
2023-11-10T13:59:36.902+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [create_user_table.sql] in 1 ms.
2023-11-10T13:59:36.903+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [insert_user.sql]
2023-11-10T13:59:36.904+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')
2023-11-10T13:59:36.904+03:00 DEBUG 1788 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [insert_user.sql] in 1 ms.
2023-11-10T13:59:36.924+03:00  INFO 1788 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I executed the actual code, I checked the `target` directory

Comment: Read the Javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html "By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test. They also use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource)."

Comment: @tgdavies thank you! But `@SpringBootTest` doesn't do that, does it? Does it mean that that magic component that allows you to write to an H2 database using MySQL (`mode=MySQL`), **which is not pulled into the context by `@DataJpaTest`** (I checked), is something I would have to sacrifice for that convenience?

Comment: @tgdavies I checked, the second test fails if I replace `@DataJpaTest` with `@SpringBootTest` (for the reason you'd expect, inserting a row with the same id)

Comment: Again from the Javadoc: "If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but use an embedded database, you should consider @ SpringBootTest combined with @ AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation."

Comment: @tgdavies Do you mean `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` ensures rollbacks too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html):

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test. They also use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource).

Please note if you rely on functionality of beans not pulled into the context by `@DataJpaTest`, it's not an option. Or rather, *including that annotation only* would not be sufficient

One such example is the "magic bean" that allows you to execute MySQL queries against an H2 database not supported by the H2 dialect (like `INSERT IGNORE INTO`). See MySQL Compatibility Mode [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html)

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MYSQL
```

Thank @tgdavies